# Widgets "skipping" ID number when duplicated

Tags: android-studio

Let's say I added (using the Palette) a textView and I can see its name in the Component Tree as `textView`. Then I duplicate this one for 10 times and the numbers add to the textView's ID; but if I delete the 9th and 10th ones and then I try to add a new textView, it will appear as `textView11` (not as `textView9` again). So it "skipped" the ones I just deleted.

I'm just curious if there is a way to reestablish "the order" in the XML code or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Android Studio is not skipping your text view id's it is happening because Android Studio is maintaining a cache for the text views you are making and not for text views you are deleting. The same also applies to other views. That's why you are seeing `textview11` after deleting `textview9` and `textview10`.

It can be solved if you do one simple thing that is just Invalidate Cache and Restart your Android Studio that can be done

Click File->Invalidate Caches/Restart and click on Invalidate Cache and Restart.

Even if you delete a TextView with id like textview2 then after Invalidating and Restarting, when you again place a TextView it will first assign `textview2` and then the preceding possible like if last is `textview9` then it will show `textview10` after that.